# How do I change the key to confirm/submit the input() function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a typeracer sort of game as a final assignment for school and I want to have it so that every time the user presses "space" the input() function would be submitted.

For example, if I were to regularly use the input() function I would need to press "enter" for the input to submit. However, I want it so that if I were to press space instead of enter the function would still submit.

If anyone knows a way around this please help.

Comment: You won't be able to rely on `input()`, instead, you'll have to monitor every key pressed and keep track of what was entered since the last space.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try using a module like keyboard or pynput (you will have to pip install them)

Answer (score 1):

I used the getch module to do this.

```
def takeInput():
word = ''
userInp = ''
# this loop ends when the user presses space indicating a new word
while userInp != " ":
    if userInp == backSpace(): # I created a whole new backspace function for this
        word = word[:-1]
        print('\r' + ' '*25)
        print('\033[F\r'+ word, end="") # goes up one line then proceeds
    else: 
        word += userInp
        word = word.strip()
    userInp = g.getche()

# erases final output 
print("\r", end="") 
sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
return word
```

With the getch module you can use getch.getche() to act as the input function. You save the users input to a variable until they press whichever key you want then save that elsewhere. So eg,

```
while inp != 'd':
    inp = getch.getche() # this displays the input
```

btw, getch is not in the standard library so do 'pip install getch' into the console to use it.